# get points of listplot in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a few graphs which took quite some time for calculations. I would like to extract the data of those plots instead of recalculing a list. I found the command `pts=Cases[(*I paste graph here*),x_Line:>First@x,Infinity];`, which works fine for my line plots but not for listplots. How can I do the same for listplots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is essentially the same except for a scatter plot you use point:

```
Cases[(*pasted graphic*), x_Point :> First@x, Infinity]
```

It may be instructive to do

```
(*paste*)//FullForm
```

Of course you really ought to just save the data before generating the plot..